# How to search both singular and plural form of word in elasticsearch?

Tags: django, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I am making elastic query using Q object and I have indexed documents, one of the documents contains "jbl speakers are great", but my query has "speaker" instead of speakers how can I find this document with query string.

I have tried match_phrase but it is unable to find this document and when I had tried query_string it threw an error saying "query_string does not support for  some key". I have also tried wildcard but that is also not working with query like

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "prod_group": "06"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "prod_group": "apparel"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "prod_cat_for_search": "+speaker*"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "2018-04-07"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```
Q('match_phrase', prod_cat_for_search='speaker')
```

I expect the output document containing speakers but 
actual output is no document containing speakers

Answer (score 4):

The type of search you are looking for can be achieved by using [stemmer token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html) at the time of indexing.

Lets see how it work using the example mapping as below:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_stemmer"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "name": "english"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the field `description` in above mapping we have used analyzer as `my_analyzer`. This analyzer will apply token filters `lowercase` and `my_stemmer`. The `my_stemmer` will apply `english` stemming on the input value.

For e.g. if we index a document as below:

```
{
   "description": "JBL speakers build with perfection"
}
```

The tokens that will get indexed are:

```
jbl
speaker
build
with
perfect
```

Notice `speakers` is indexed as `speaker` and `perfection` as `perfect`.

Now if you search for `speakers` or `speaker` both will match. Similarly, if you search for `perfect` the above document will match.

Why `speakers` or `perfection` will match might be a question arising in your mind. The reason for this is that by default elastic search apply the same analyzer that was used while indexing at the time of searching as well. So if you search for `perfection` it will be actually searching for `perfect` and hence the match.

More on [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming).