# Less restrictive search doesn't return any hits in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

The query below returns hits, for example where `name` is "Balances by bank":

```
GET /_search

{ "query": {
    "multi_match": { "query": "Balances",
                     "fields": ["name","descrip","notes"] 
                   }
           }
 }
```

So why this doesn't return anything? Note that the query is less restrictive, the word is "Balance" and not "Balances" with an s.

```
GET /_search

{ "query": {
    "multi_match": { "query": "Balance",
                     "fields": ["name","descrip","notes"] 
                   }
           }
 }
```

What search would return both?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566338/how-to-search-both-singular-and-plural-form-of-word-in-elasticsearch/55567692#55567692

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your mapping to be able to do that.

If you didn't specified a mapping with specific analyzers when creating your index, elasticsearch will use the default mapping and analyzer.

The default mapping will map each text field as both `text` and `keyword`, so you will be able to performe full text search (match part of the string) and keyword search (match the whole string), but it will use the `standard` [analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html).

With the `standard` analyzer your example *Balances by bank* becomes the following list of tokens: [*Balances*, *by*, *bank*], those items are added to the inverted index and elasticsearch can find the documents when you search for any of them.

When you search for just *Balance*, this term does not exist in the inverted index and elasticsearch returns nothing.

To be able to return both *Balance* and *Balances* you need to change your mapping and use the `analyzer` for the english language, this analyzer will reduce your terms to their stem and match *Balance*, *Balances* as also *Balancing*, *Balanced*, *Balancer* etc.

Look at this [part of the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/analysis.html) to see how the analysis process work.

And of course, you can also search for *Balance** and it will return both *Balance* and *Balances*, but it is a different query.